# Mac Application - Disable specific USB port

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos

There is any way to I disable/enable a specific USB Port with my application ?

Comment: why would you want to do this? there probably is but it would be very hacky...

Comment: is for a personal app...

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is no, especially if your process is not running with root privileges and/or using SPI.

Comment: is for a personal app isn't a reason why, they reason they asked why, is there may be a more appropriate solution based on what you want to do, versus how you think it should be done.

Comment: One (admittedly silly) use case: turning a USB bias light on or off without having to reach behind a Thunderbolt display.  That might be an entirely different beast than disabling a specific USB port, though, based on how the Thunderbolt displays connect to a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this from user space, and even within the kernel it could be tricky: I think you would need to install a dummy I/O Kit driver which matches all USB devices and/or interfaces. This could be tricky as existing drivers would take precedence, so you'd need to work around that. Once matched, you would check the port in the driver's `probe()` method and return true if it was one of the disallowed ports. This would stop other drivers from grabbing the device, which would essentially disable it.